# How to avoid having a complete path for dynamic linking?

Tags: c++, path, linker, shared-libraries, ldd

I have generated a dynamic library libA.so. Now I want to generate another dynamic library libB.so that is linked to libA.so.

With ldd command, I see the absolute path to libA.so:

```
ldd full_path_to_libB/libB.so
    libx.so => full_path_to_libx (0x....)
    .
    .
    fullpath_to_libA/libA.so (0x....)
```

But I would like to avoid having only the complete library path for libA.so to get this with ldd :

```
ldd full_path_to_libB/libB.so
    libx.so => full_path_to_libx (0x....)
    .
    .
    libA.so => full_path_to_libA/libA.so (addr)
```

This assumes for example to add full_path_to_libB to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

To add an extra library repository, I have tried to add some options to the linker, but nothing worked.

```
g++: error: libA.so not found
```

Is it possible to avoid to get only the complete path libA.so and how, with which option?

Comment: Are you building it from command line? Can you post what flags you're using to build libB.so and in what order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The correct way to do is as SergeyA said:

> g++ -shared -fPIC -L. -lA libB.cpp -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN' -o libB.so

For when the executable you'll build with your libraries is in the same path as your libraries you can do this:

g++ -shared -fPIC -L. -lA libB.cpp -Wl,-rpath,. -o libB.so

it should link to local (-L. adding . as path for building and -rpath,. for runtime). As SergeyA pointed out, . is $PWD, not $ORIGIN.

Answer (score 1):

This is what $ORIGIN is for. In order to use it, you'd need following flag to the linker when linking libB.so: `,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'` This will ensure that libB.so will always try to find libA by it's side.

Pleas note, however, that ldd is still going to display full path to libA.

Comment: Then it is not necessary to put the full path to libA.so in the gcc command line, is it?

Comment: @FlashMcQueen, you still need the path to libA.so when linking. But you wouldn't need it when executing you executable.

Comment: Ok and then the flag is -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'?

Comment: I have just tried but I still get only the full path to libA.so

Comment: @FlashMcQueen, I told you so - ldd will always display the full path, since it is going to resolve origin. But you can see that if you move libB.so to a different location (together with libA.so) the full path will reflect the new location of libA.

Comment: Is there a reason not to do -L. and -rpath,.?

Comment: @Andrej, -L is neccessary, but I am not talking about that. `rpath,.` though will not do what $ORIGIN does.

Comment: but rpath,. will still resolve to local folder if you move both libraries to a new location though, right?

Comment: @Andrej, no. `rpath,.` will refer to the current location ($PWD), not the location of the library/executable.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Andrej's solution worked fine. Thank you all.

Comment: @SergeyA, oh, sorry, good point! You mean for when the executable that's using libB, and libA through it, is not in the same directory. Upvoting your answer and editing mine accordingly.